# Problem with merging wildcard of subdomains with wildcard of few sub-subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns, subdomain, wildcard

I have EHCP installed because it's simple and helpful on server with few FTP accounts and websites. It's testing only server.

**Problem is: I can access *.avki.zgarnijlicke.pl, *.kierowca.zgarnijlicke.pl but *.zgarnijlicke.pl isn't working.**

My config's are:
a) Apache template:

`#____________start of {domainname}__paneluser:{panelusername}_reseller:{reseller}_id:{id}____________
# explanation  {aciklama}`

<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName   {domainname}
        ServerAlias  www.{domainname}
        # buraya aliaslar yazilacak..
        {aliases}

```
    UseCanonicalName Off
    DocumentRoot {homedir}/httpdocs
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ {homedir}/httpdocs/cgi-bin/

    \# this combined log format is understandable by webalizer... some other formats are not recognised by webalizer.. thats why, specified here explicitly.. 

    LogFormat &quot;%h %l %u %t \&quot;%r\&quot; %&gt;s %b \&quot;%{Referer}i\&quot; \&quot;%{User-Agent}i\&quot;&quot; combined
    LogFormat &quot;%v:%h %l %u %t \&quot;%r\&quot; %&gt;s %b \&quot;%{Referer}i\&quot; \&quot;%{User-Agent}i\&quot;&quot; vhost_combined
    CustomLog  {homedir}/logs/access_log combined
    CustomLog  /var/log/apache_common_access_log vhost_combined

    php_admin_value open_basedir {homedir}
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir {homedir}/phptmpdir
    php_admin_value session.save_path {homedir}/phptmpdir

    AccessFileName .htaccess

    &lt;Directory {homedir}&gt;
    AllowOverride all
    &lt;/Directory&gt;
    {customhttp}
```

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName  webmail.{domainname}
ServerAlias  mail.{domainname}
ServerAlias  email.{domainname}

DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/ehcp/webmail

```
    LogFormat &quot;%h %l %u %t \&quot;%r\&quot; %&gt;s %b \&quot;%{Referer}i\&quot; \&quot;%{User-Agent}i\&quot;&quot; combined
    LogFormat &quot;%v:%h %l %u %t \&quot;%r\&quot; %&gt;s %b \&quot;%{Referer}i\&quot; \&quot;%{User-Agent}i\&quot;&quot; vhost_combined
    CustomLog  {homedir}/logs/access_log combined
    CustomLog  /var/log/apache_common_access_log vhost_combined

    php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/vhosts/ehcp/webmail
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/www/vhosts/ehcp/webmail/data
    php_admin_value session.save_path /var/www/vhosts/ehcp/webmail/data
```

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName  cpanel.{domainname}
ServerAlias  panel.{domainname}
ServerAlias  ehcp.{domainname}
ServerAlias  cp.{domainname}

DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/ehcp/

```
    LogFormat &quot;%v:%h %l %u %t \&quot;%r\&quot; %&gt;s %b \&quot;%{Referer}i\&quot; \&quot;%{User-Agent}i\&quot;&quot; vhost_combined
    CustomLog  /var/log/apache_common_access_log vhost_combined

    php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/vhosts/ehcp/
```

</VirtualHost>
#____________end of {domainname}__paneluser:{panelusername}_reseller:{reseller}_id:{id}____________

b) apache Aliases:

`*.zgarnijlicke.pl
*.avki.zgarnijlicke.pl
*.kierowca.zgarnijlicke.pl`

c) DNS template

`$TTL    86400
@       IN      SOA     ns.{domainname}. {dnsemail} (
                        {serial}    ; Serial
                        10800  ; Refresh
                        1200    ; Retry
                        86400 ; Expire
                        86400 ); Minimum`

{domainname}.           IN NS   ns.{domainname}.
ns.{domainname}.        IN A    {dnsip}
ns1.{domainname}.       IN A    {dnsip}
ns2.{domainname}.       IN A    {dnsip}
dns.{domainname}.       IN A    {dnsip}
dns1.{domainname}.       IN A    {dnsip}
dns2.{domainname}.       IN A    {dnsip}
{domainname}.           IN A    {webip}
mail.{domainname}.      IN A    {mailip}
smtp.{domainname}.   IN A    {webip}
webmail.{domainname}.   IN A    {webip}
ftp.{domainname}.       IN CNAME        {domainname}.
www.{domainname}.       IN CNAME        {domainname}.
{domainname}.           IN MX  10 mail.{domainname}.
{domainname}.           IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx"

{customdns}
*.{domainname} 14400 IN A {domainname}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
Aliases:

`*.zgarnijlicke.pl`

DNS template:

`$TTL    86400
@       IN      SOA     ns.{domainname}. {dnsemail} (
                        {serial}     ; Serial
                        10800   ; Refresh
                        1200     ; Retry
                        86400  ; Expire
                        86400 ) ; Minimum`

{domainname}.           IN NS   ns.{domainname}.
ns.{domainname}.        IN A    {dnsip}
ns1.{domainname}.       IN A    {dnsip}
ns2.{domainname}.       IN A    {dnsip}
dns.{domainname}.       IN A    {dnsip}
dns1.{domainname}.       IN A    {dnsip}
dns2.{domainname}.       IN A    {dnsip}
{domainname}.           IN A    {webip}
mail.{domainname}.      IN A    {mailip}
smtp.{domainname}.   IN A    {webip}
webmail.{domainname}.   IN A    {webip}
ftp.{domainname}.       IN CNAME        {domainname}.
www.{domainname}.       IN CNAME        {domainname}.
{domainname}.           IN MX  10 mail.{domainname}.
{domainname}.           IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx"

{customdns}

- IN A    {webip}

Apache template without changes.

Now, everything it's working. asd.qwe.qwe.asd.qwe.asd.zgarnijlicke.pl and hello.zgarnijlicke.pl

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a domain name as the right hand side of an A record assignment.
*.{domainname} 14400 IN A {domainname}

Try the following instead:

*.{domainname} 14400 IN CNAME {domainname}

or if you need to use an A record then try

*.{domainname} 14400 IN A {webip}

Comment: *.{domainname} 14400 IN A {webip}
AND
*.{domainname} 14400 IN CNAME {domainname}
both are working only for the *.avki and *.kierowca. *.zgarnijlicke.pl isn't working.